# Peut-on dire « partenaire parole » au lieu de « interlocuteur » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, néerlandais

Pour indiquer quelqu’un avec qui on parle, on dit *interlocuteur*. En néerlandais on a « gespreksgenoot ». Si je traduis le mot néerlandais en français littéralement, je reçois « partenaire / compagnon de parole ». Quand j’entends le mot *compagnon*, je pense à accompagner quelqu’un, faire du chemin ensemble. J’éviterais donc l’emploi de « compagnon de parole ».

Quant à « partenaire » au contraire, j’ai vu une bouteille de l’eau qui portait une étiquette qui montrait les mots « vôtre partenaire minceur », une façon de parler imagée. Alors j’utilisais le mot « partenaire paroles » quelque fois, et tout français avec qui je parlais semblaient de comprendre mes propos.

Plus tard, j’ai cherché sur la toile quelle fonction ce mot pouvait remplir. Le Wiktionnaire ne donne pas beaucoup de renseignements. Il dit que le mot peut désigner quelqu’un qui prend part à un jeu, quelqu’un ou quelque chose qui est lié à une entreprise, ou un *concubin*. Les emplois figurés manquaient entièrement. Alors j’ai lu un aperçu du Wikipédia ou les quatre sens sont mis ensemble. Mais rien n’indiquait que je puisse utiliser la tournure sans soucis.

J’espère que vous pourrez me dire si « partenaire parole » est usité, et si cette tournure comporte des subtilités inattendues.

Comment: Non, "partenaire parole" n'existe pas à ma connaissance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selon moi, **non**. Contrairement à Laure, l’emploi de « partenaire parole » provoquerait chez moi une demande d’explication. Effectivement, je pourrais peut-être déduire le sens de l’expression du contexte, mais je buterais dessus quoi qu’il arrive.

Je te conseille donc de préférer le terme « interlocuteur ».

Qui plus est, et comme le signale toujours Laure, « partenaire [quelque chose] » est plutôt employé en marketing et la publicité. Je me suis certes habitué à la construction (que je trouve moche) dans ce cadre, mais dans une conversation cela me dérangerait. Justement *parce que* j’aurais l’impression d’avoir affaire à une publicité.

« Partenaire de parole » me dérange moins, mais je l’interprèterais différemment. Suite à un discours tenu à deux, par exemple, je supposerais que l’expression employée par un des orateurs désignerait l’autre, par exemple.

Comment: Je ne vois aucune opposition entre ta réponse et la mienne (si je comprends bien ton emploi de "contrairement"). Je trouve que nous disons la même chose. La seule raison pour laquelle je ne demanderais pas d'explication c'est parce que sachant que mon interlocuteur est néerlandais je passe rapidement de "parole" à la racine germanique et j'interprète tout de suite "parole" comme voulant dire "discussion" et du coup, je comprends ce qu'il veut dire dans le contexte. J'ai bien dit "je" et pas "les Français" ou "nous".

Comment: Si quelqu’un emploie « partenaire parole », je ne comprends *a priori* pas ce qu’il veut dire. Contrairement à toi.

Answer (score 4):

Je comprends ce que tu veux dire quand tu dis « partenaire parole », bien que ce soit une expression que je n'ai jamais entendue en français. Et je l'interprète en sachant que tu n'es pas francophone. Venant d'un francophone je pense que l’interpréterais différemment.

Depuis quelques années l'expression « partenaire xx » est employée en marketing pour désigner une marque en tant qu'interlocuteur. On a des slogans publicitaires qui parlent du « partenaire minceur » (le produit qui va aider à faire maigrir) du « partenaire électricité » (fournisseur d'électricité), du « partenaire voyages » (agence de voyage...), du « partenaire télécommunication » etc....

Si un francophone dont je connaîtrais la bonne maîtrise du français me parlait de son  « partenaire parole » je soupçonnerais une relation commerciale et penserais soit à un psy quelconque (qui « libère » la parole), à une école de diction ou quelque chose de ce genre. Et peut-être y verrais-je un sous-entendu ironique. J'allais écrire que je penserais à une agence en communication mais j'ai regardé sur [google](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=parteniare%20parole&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=&gws_rd=ssl#as_qdr=all&lr=&q=%22partenaire%20d%27avenir%22) et les agences en communication semblent vouloir prendre le créneau « partenaire d'avenir ».

Answer (score 3):

Je penche du même côté qu'Édouard en ce sens que si on me sortait ça comme expression, ça prendrait de court au premier abord.

Sans explication supplémentaire, je déduirais probablement "partenaire de conversation" et j'imaginerais un interlocuteur dont le rôle est limité à aider cette personne à pratiquer une langue étrangère qu'elle est en train d'apprendre.

Le mot « partenaire » suggère, à mon avis, une relation réciproque dans un contexte quelconque (si informel soit-il), nuance que je ne ressens pas avec le mot « interlocuteur ».

Exemple concret : quand je vais au magasin, le préposé est brièvement mon interlocuteur,  mais je ne le qualifierais pas de partenaire de conversation. Toutefois, je ne saurais dire jusqu'à quel point d'autres francophones font la même distinction.